# Присвоить значения полям класса из Dictionary в цикле...

Tags: c#, классы

Здравствуйте, ребята. помогите новичку.

```
ClassVivod[] vivod = new ClassVivod[dic1.Count];
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dic1)
    {
        vivod[i]._key = pair.Key;
        vivod[i]._valueXML_1=pair.Value;
        i++;
    }
```

выводит ошибку:NullReferenceException Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: Может проблема в ClassVivod. Приложите его код сюда. Так будет проще.

Comment: как раз таки проблема в ClassVivod. я там объявил поля и задал свойство get set для каждого поля.и все.что еще надо было?я просто с такими классами не работал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
var vivod = dic1.Select(
        kvp => new ClassVivod()
               {
                   _key = kvp.Key,
                   _valueXML_1 = kvp.Value
               })
    .ToArray();
```

Для случая со вторым Dictionary можно попробовать так:

```
var vivod = dic1.Select(kvp =>
    {
        string xml2; // или какой там тип значения у dic2
        dict2.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out xml2);
        return new ClassVivod()
               {
                   _key = kvp.Key,
                   _valueXML_1 = kvp.Value
                   _valueXML_2 = xml2
               })
    }.ToArray();
```

Comment: Благодарю, Влад. У ClassVivod есть еще одно поле _valueXML_2. Туда надо записывать значение из dic2 при условии что _key = dic2.Key..если не сложно, подскажи как.

Comment: @zirrama: обновил ответ.